# ubuntu + cinnamon + virtualbox - software rendering or no menu bar

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, cinnamon

I'm trying to get Cinnamon (3.6.7) running on Ubuntu (18.04) in my VirtualBox (5.2) which is running on Windows 10.

If I use the "default" setup of VirtualBox, Cinnamon gives me a warning that it is running in "software rendering" mode.  I've done some searching, and the general consensus is to turn on 3D rendering in the VirtualBox settings, and increase the graphics memory to 128Mb.  I can do that, but then the taskbar does not appear at the bottom of the page.

Turning off 3D acceleration gives me back the taskbar, but gives me the warning again.